# SwiftUI List styles

Tags: watchkit, swiftui

I'm writing an Apple Watch app and I want to create a list just like this one in the Settings menu where the rows in the middle of the list are rectangles whereas the top and bottom are rounded rectangles. Is this a type of List style? [image]

Comment: By the way here's how to take screenshots on Apple Watch: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204673.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do, though it requires using `GeometryReader` to handle drawing the rounded corners.

There is a great post by [swiftui-lab.com](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/) that explains how to make the certain corners of a view rounded. Here is the code.

```swift
struct RoundedCorners: View {
    var color: Color = .blue
    var tl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var tr: CGFloat = 0.0
    var bl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var br: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in

                let w = geometry.size.width
                let h = geometry.size.height

                // Make sure we do not exceed the size of the rectangle
                let tr = min(min(self.tr, h/2), w/2)
                let tl = min(min(self.tl, h/2), w/2)
                let bl = min(min(self.bl, h/2), w/2)
                let br = min(min(self.br, h/2), w/2)

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w / 2.0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: 0))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: tr), radius: tr, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - br))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - br, y: h - br), radius: br, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h - bl), radius: bl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tl))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: tl, y: tl), radius: tl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
            }
            .fill(self.color)
        }
    }
}
```

We can then make a small example. Taking an array of items we can create a `List`. We will need the indices of the items so that we can tell which item is first (index of `0`) and last (index of `count - 1`). The `.listRowBackground` modifier allows us to set the background of our rows so we will use that to set the view on it.

We create a helper function `createRoundedCorners` which will takes the index of the row and the number of rows that exist. This returns a `RoundedCorrners` view that  the top left and right corners of the first row to be rounded and similarly the bottom left and right corners of the end row.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["Within 2 Minutes of Last Use",
                 "Within 1 Hour of Last Use",
                 "Always"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                Text(self.items[index]).font(.system(size: 24))
                    .listRowBackground(self.createRoundedCorners(at: index, count: self.items.count))
            }
        }
    }

    /// This function creates rounded corners for the first and last items in an array
    func createRoundedCorners(at index: Int, count: Int) -> RoundedCorners {
        switch index {
        case 0:
            return RoundedCorners(color: .blue, tl: 15, tr: 15, bl: 0, br: 0)
        case (count - 1):
            return RoundedCorners(color: .blue, tl: 0, tr: 0, bl: 15, br: 15)
        default:
            return RoundedCorners(color: .blue, tl: 0, tr: 0, bl: 0, br: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following results

List at the top:

[image: list at top]

List at the bottom:

[image: list at bottom]

Answer (score -1):

No, in SwiftUI Lists are very limited for configurations.
I recommend you to try making your own custom List-like view using ScrollView.